# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, 290, 290, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, jupyter-notebook, neural-network

I am trying to implement the game of Rock, paper and scissors in jupyther notebook using tensorflow with a neural network, the code I am trying to implement is this one: https://learnopencv.com/playing-rock-paper-scissors-with-ai/

When I use my webcam It works correctly, but when I use a dslr camera it doesnt work

The specific line when the code broke is here:

```
history = model.fit(x=augment.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=batchsize), validation_data=(testX, testY), 
steps_per_epoch= len(trainX) // batchsize, epochs=epochs)
```

The complete error is :

```
Epoch 1/15
7/7 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0831 - accuracy: 0.6154
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17300/1526770187.py in <module>
      4 
      5 # Start training
----> 6 history = model.fit(x=augment.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=batchsize), validation_data=(testX, testY), 
      7 steps_per_epoch= len(trainX) // batchsize, epochs=epochs)
      8 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = process_traceback_frames(e.traceback_)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in tf__test_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag_.converted_call(ag.ld(step_function), (ag.ld(self), ag_.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1557, in test_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1546, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1535, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.test_step(data)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1499, in test_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, 290, 290, 3)
```

THE COMPLETE CODE OF THE PROGRAM IS HERE: https://learnopencv.com/playing-rock-paper-scissors-with-ai/

Comment: impossible. that code doesn't resize to 290x290, it resizes to 224x224. did you copy it wrong?

Comment: you are right the code is history = model.fit(x=augment.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=batchsize), validation_data=(testX, testY), 
steps_per_epoch= len(trainX) // batchsize, epochs=epochs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, it seems like the shape of the input images is `(290, 290, 3)`. Resizing the images to `(224, 224, 3)` will solve the issue. Please add the following line before normalizing.

```
#Resizing images
images = np.resize(images,(400, 224, 224, 3))
#Normalizing images
images = np.array(images, dtype="float") / 255.0
```